# Templated class whose argument must be another templated class

Tags: c++, templates, nested

Well, this is what I'm trying to achieve. I have a struct like this:

```
template<typename...Ts> struct s
{
    template<int...Is> struct r
    {
        // whatever
    };
};
```

Now I'd like to write one more templated structure:

```
template<typename r> struct q
{
    //
};
```

The template should accept specialisations of `struct r` and I'd like to have access to template arguments of this instantiation.

To make myself more clear: I'd like to be able to write something like this:

```
using some_specialisation_of_q = q< s<T1,T2,T3>::r<5,6,7> >;
some_specialisation_of_q varname;
```

AND I'd like to be able to have access to `T1,T2,T3`, `5,6,7` (or any other template arguments passed to specialize `s` and `r`) in the definition of `q`.

My first attempt was something like that:

```
template<template<typename...Ts> template<int...Is> typename R, typename= typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<R, s<Ts...>::r<Is...>>::value>::type>
struct q
{
    //
}
```

But unfortunately this produces compiler errors.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: `r` will have to publish `Ts...`. It's a non-deduced context otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no way to deduce `Ts...` from a specialization of `r` without its cooperation. So let's publish the type:

```
template<typename...Ts> struct s
{
    template<int...Is> struct r
    {
        using outer_type = s;
    };
};
```

Then extract with partial specialization

```
template<class T, class = typename T::outer_type, class = T>
struct q;

template<template <int...> class R, class...Ts, int...Is>
struct q<R<Is...>, s<Ts...>, typename s<Ts...>::template r<Is...>>{
};
```